# Best way to modify a java pre-existing regular expression to allow one new character

Tags: java, regex, string

There is this pre-existing regex, which on one condition should allow one more character:

```
String regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF \\-&*()_+|~=`{}\\[\\]:\";'<>?,.]{0,900}$";

if (condition is true) { 
      regex = regex .substring(0, 47) + "/" + regex.substring(47, 
      regex.length());
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and where is changing the code problematic for you? There are sites like https://regex101.com/ which will explain what the part of a regular expression do. Have you tried those?

Comment: This is not a good idea to modify such a pattern dynamically. It would make more sense to build it from blocks. That is, define the ranges separately and put them inside the negated character class as a final step. And only escape the chars you must escape in character classes.

Comment: @Corion I will look into that website for further reference. But that website dosen't supports Java it seems.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know its not a good idea, that is why I am asking what could be the best way to add an extra character.

Comment: Do it manually to avoid issues. Else, if possible, change the approach I suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would probably be to define them both seperately and then use them based on your if condition.

```
    String regex1 = "^[a-zA-Z0-9\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF \\-&*()_+|~=`{}\\[\\]:\";'<>?,.]{0,900}$";
    String regex2 = "^[a-zA-Z0-9\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF \\-&*()_+|~=`{}\\[\\]:\";'<>?,/.]{0,900}$";

    String currentRegex;
    if (condition is true) { 
          currentRegex = regex2;
    } else {
        currentRegex = regex1;
    }
```

Comment: This will contradict the code reusability statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a charclass union:

```
String myCharclass = "[a-zA-Z0-9\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF \\-&*()_+|~=`{}\\[\\]:\";'<>?,.]"

if (condition)
    myCharclass = "[/" + charclass + "]"; // a character class union

String regex = "^" + myCharclass + "{0,900}$";
```

If written using [almson-regex](https://github.com/almson/almson-regex) it would look like:

```
import static net.almson.util.Regex.*;

String myCharclass = charclassUnion (LETTER, DIGIT, charclassRange ('\u00A0', '\uD7FF'), charclassRange ('\uF900', '\uFDCF'), charclassRange ('\uFDF0','\uFFEF'), charclass (' ', '-', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', '|', '~', '=', '`', '{', '}', '[', ']', ':', '"', ';', '\'', '<', '>', '?', ',', '.'));

if (condition)
    myCharclass = charclassUnion (myCharclass, charclass ('/'));

regex = START_BOUNDARY + between (0, 900, myCharclass) + END_BOUNDARY;
```